# Aggregating two values in same select statement. Second aggregation is decreasing in value for each row for some reason

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm currently trying to aggregate two values simultaneously in one select statement; however, the second aggregated value is decreasing for some reason. I know what I'm doing is wrong, but I don't understand why it's wrong (assuming it's the very last code block). Mainly just trying to better understand what's going on, and why it's happening.

I already have a corrected query that works (at the bottom)

*Note:* Query and outputs are simplified, please ignore any syntax issues. Additionally, in real query, I need to keep `subscription_start_date` field in until the end.

**Query with issue (very last block):**

```
WITH max_product_user_count AS (
-- The total count is obtained when "days" = 0
SELECT
    subscription_start_date,
    datediff('days', subscription_start_date, subscription_date) AS days,
    product,
    num_users AS total_user_count
FROM users
WHERE days = 0
),

daily_product_user_count AS (
-- As "days" go up, the number of subscribers for each start date/product type decreases
SELECT
    subscription_start_date,
    datediff('days', subscription_start_date, subscription_date) AS days,
    product,
    num_users AS daily_user_count
FROM users
WHERE days IN (0,5,14,21,30,33,60)
) 

-- Trying to aggregate by product and day, across all subscription start dates
SELECT
    d.product,
    d.days,
    SUM(daily_user_count) AS daily_count,
    SUM(total_user_count) AS total_count
FROM daily_product_user_count d 
INNER JOIN max_product_user_count m ON d.subscription_start_date = m.subscription_start_date
AND d.product = m.product
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

**Current Output:**

```
PRODUCT       DAYS  DAILY_COUNT TOTAL_COUNT
product_1     0     10000       10000
product_1     5     99231       99781
product_1     14    96124       98123
product_1     21    85123       96441
product_1     30    23412       94142
product_1     33    12931       92111
product_1     60    10231       90123
```

**Expected Output:**

```
PRODUCT       DAYS  DAILY_COUNT TOTAL_COUNT
product_1     0     10000       10000
product_1     5     99231       10000
product_1     14    96124       10000
product_1     21    85123       10000
product_1     30    23412       10000
product_1     33    12931       10000
product_1     60    10231       10000
```

**Updated correct query:**

```
WITH max_product_user_count AS (

SELECT
    subscription_start_date,
    datediff('days', subscription_start_date, subscription_date) AS days,
    product,
    num_users AS total_user_count
FROM users
WHERE days = 0
),

max_user_count_aggregation AS (

SELECT
    product,
    SUM(total_user_count) AS total_count 
FROM max_product_user_count
GROUP BY  1
),

daily_product_user_count AS (

SELECT
    subscription_start_date,
    datediff('days', subscription_start_date, subscription_date) AS days,
    product,
    num_users AS daily_user_count
FROM users
WHERE days IN (0,5,14,21,30,33,60)
) 

daily_user_count_aggregation AS (

SELECT
    product,
    days,
    SUM(daily_user_count) AS daily_count 
FROM daily_product_user_count
GROUP BY  1
)

SELECT
    d.product,
    d.days,
    daily_count,
    total_count
FROM daily_user_count_aggregation d 
INNER JOIN max_user_count_aggregation m ON d.product = m.product
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: In `Updated correct query` you are joining only on `product` but in 'Aggregated Query' you are joining on `subscription_start_date` and `Product`. which will filter the records. due to that your sum is decreased

Comment: @S.Zhong . . . Your query is strange.  I would expect the total to be *less* than the daily count, because the filtering is different.  In addition, you are filtering on `days` and also defining it in the `select` -- but the version in the `select` is not used for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, the query is way more complicated than necessary.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT datediff('days', subscription_start_date, subscription_date) AS days,
       product,
       SUM(num_users) FILTER (WHERE days IN (0, 5, 14, 21, 30, 33, 60)) AS daily_user_count,
       SUM(num_users) FILTER (WHERE days = 0) AS total_user_count
FROM users
GROUP BY days, product;
```

I would advise you to ask a new question, explaining the logic you want to implement and providing reasonable sample data and desired results.